# Facebook Login SDK. How to get verified mobile number?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Been looking all over the Facebook sdk documentation and there is no api to get the verified mobile number. All of the answers I've found claim that it is no longer possible blah blah blah. If this is true, how does Uber currently have access to request the verified mobile number permission? Using old api versions is not allowed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe they have a deal with Facebook?

Comment: The thing is they are not the only one. Grab supports verified mobile number as well. check it out. I'm still curious on how this is done